# Kernel source package for 3.16 in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: kernel

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel 3.16.0-41. I was looking for the kernel source but the kernel-source metapackage is pointing at 3.13 and I can't see any source packages refering to 3.16. What should I be looking for?

Comment: What do you need the source for?

Comment: For driver development

Comment: Then clone it from git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [linux-source](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-source-3.16.0_3.16.0-41.57_all.deb) from 14.10. In 14.04.2 that kernel is installed.

If you need Ubuntu kernel for development, you can clone it from git.

```
git clone http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-utopic.git
```

Comment: Yes, I think I got a bit fixated on a 'missing' package rather than looking at the alternative methods of getting the source.